# is it possible to add same line using Ansible lineinfile module?

Tags: ansible

I've the following playbook which try to print the exclamation mark..But the test.txt file alway have one line "-e ! \".

Is it the behavior of lineinfile that you can't add the SAME line more that once? Can I disable this behavior? Or is that any workaround?

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
      items_list:
          - '!'
          - '!'
          - '!'
  tasks:
      - name: "append all items"
      lineinfile:
          dest: "test.txt"
          line: '-e {{ item }} \'
      with_items: "{{ items_list }}"

      - name: "append all items"
      lineinfile:
          dest: "test.txt"
          line: '-e {{ item }} \'
      with_items: "{{ items_list }}"


devops@devops:~/ANSIBLE$ more test.txt
-e ! \
```

Comment: No, you can't add the same line more than one using `lineinfile:` because it has done what you've asked and added **that line** to the file. Is your objective just to have those 3 lines in the file, or is there some complicating circumstance?

Comment: No you can't, you can use `blockinfile` to put several lines in a file

Comment: @Matthew L Daniel...I want to generate Cisco config. file which have "!" to separate different section...

Answer (score 1):

Adding multiple lines is not the purpose of the `lineinfile` module.

The [description present on the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) is very clear:

> - This module ensures a particular line is in a file, or replace an existing line using a back-referenced regular expression.
> - This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only. See the replace module if you want to change multiple,
>     similar lines or check blockinfile if you want to insert/update/remove
>     a block of lines in a file. For other cases, see the copy or template
>     modules.

So no you can't. To achieve the desired behavior use one of the modules suggested above.